# Word meaning "of or relating to trains"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nautical) the word *nautical* means:

> of or relating to sailors, ships, or navigation

Is there a single word that might mean something similar to "of or relating to train operators, trains, or railroads"?

**Examples:**

1. I want a nautical themed room.
2. I want a [train] themed room.

Comment: ***Railroad Themed Restaurants*** 
 http://www.gregariousrailfan.com/Restaurants.html

Comment: Yeah, "railroad" would be the usual adjective in the US.

Comment: I disagree that 'railroad' is an adjective.  For example, [Merriam–Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/railroad) does not recognise it as such, only as a noun or a verb.  (OED has the adjective [railroadish](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/157560#eid26959222), which, however, does not mean "of or relating to a railroad" but, charmingly, "at a railroad pace".)

Comment: Say: "I want a train-themed room"

Comment: Your example sentence conflicts with the comparison to the adjective "nautical". "I want a __ themed room" sounds most natural with a noun or adverb, not an adjective. (For example, I think "I want a nautically themed room" sounds better than "I want a nautical themed room.")

Comment: @LSpice Nouns can function as adjectives. "Have you read this train book?" "No. I was watching the game at the football stadium."

Comment: As sumelic says, your example does not correspond at all well to your question. I'm tempted to edit, but I'd feel the need to forestall such simplistic answers as 'use railway / railway- as an attributive noun' and such offbeat answers as 'ferroequinological'.

Comment: Locomotive. I expect there's also a particular fancy word for trainspotting (like philately for stamp collecting).

Comment: You could try "trainal" (heh)

Comment: @DavidRicherby That is incorrect. Nouns ***cannot*** "function as adjectives".  Using a noun attributively is not “functioning as an adjective”; it fails all the adjective tests and passes all the noun tests, so it remains a noun even in attributive position, where it creates an improvised compound noun. Not all noun modifiers are adjectives!

Comment: @HotLicks You’ve confused "modifying a noun" with "adjective": *railroad* is never an adjective. Ever. A *railroad crossing* has two nouns; a *cog railroad crossing* has three.  There are no "easily railroad crossings" nor "very railroad crossings" nor "often railroad crossings", because *railroad* is never an adjective. Just because all cats are carnivores doesn't mean that all carnivores are cats.

Comment: I've never heard of "easily hot pies" either.  Nor "often red apples".

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't it be "nautically themed"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Americans at least are a lot more likely to say "I want a boat themed room" than "I want a nautically themed room". Actually, what we would really say is "I want my room to have a boat/train theme."

Comment: I had always thought that "ferrovial" was the adjective meaning railroad-related, but after a google search to confirm, it seems that it's only used in Spanish.

Comment: I always thought the word was "ferrovial" too - I'm fairly sure I've seen it in English somewhere.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best fit is **locomotive**.

As an adjective (from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/locomotive)):

> of or relating to locomotives.

Where as a noun:

> a self-propelled, vehicular engine, powered by steam, a diesel, or electricity, for pulling or, sometimes, pushing a train or individual railroad cars.

'Locomotive' can have a broader meaning relating to other forms of transport though so it may not always be specific enough.

Comment: Yes, this is the best answer. Technically it's not exactly the meaning as an adjective, but in use, it definitely fits the bill for what you asked for.

Comment: *locomotive* is the adjective to *locomotion*, ie. movement.

Comment: "Locomotive" in this sense is no more an adjective than "train" is.

Comment: I disagree. Locomotives are a specific aspect of railways, so a locomotive-themed room isn't the same thing as a railway-themed room. It's like answering "What's an adjective that can be used to describe things from the USA?" with "Californian".

Comment: @David Richerby You see why a need is felt by some to pre-empt poor answers? // The cable-hauled (stationary engine) sections of the old High Peak Railway would be off-topic according to this answer.

Comment: @sumelic Actually, "locomotive" was originally an adjective. The idea that it can be a noun is about fifty years later (mid C17th).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If somebody had commented "Not locomotive because that means something else", then you'd have a point. I continue to dispute that a correct answer can be "poor", regardless of how obvious it is. If there is a better word, then my answer that I'm not aware of anything but train/railway/railroad is incorrect; but if there are no other words, it's the correct answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Yes, locomotive was originally an adjective, but what I'm saying is it doesn't behave much like an adjective *when used as a synonym for "train".* It can be used attributively, and that's basically all. You can't use it as a predicate adjective (for example, we can't say "The theme *is locomotive*", although we can say "The theme is nautical") and it isn't gradable ("*very locomotive" to mean "very related to trains" is completely impossible, whereas "very nautical" is tolerable).

Comment: If this ends up being the term you use, I guess that would make someone a "locophile" if they really like trains...?

Comment: *locomotive* leaves out "the land, stations, rolling stock, [operators,] and other related property". 99% of [trains] are not locomotives.

Comment: Terrible fit.  **A locomotive is not a train**.  That's like calling a PC a "hard drive" or confusing a pickup truck and a semi. It is common, but reflects carelessness and ignorance of both railways and language.

Comment: @adjan while that is true, it is a different usage (subject matter) than OP is interested in.  Carlos there are words for that; railfan, trainspotter, or the vulgar "foamer".

Answer (score 21):

You might try **ferroequinological**.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ferroequinologist):

> ferroequinologist
>
> : railfan
>
> Origin and Etymology of ferroequinologist
>
> ferroequino- “iron horse ” (from ferro- + equino-, from Latin equinus equine + -logy + -ist

Comment: It's cute, but unfortunately it wouldn't be widely understood.

Comment: @Morgoth and thus making it a poor answer, in my book. The entire purpose of language is to be understood.

Comment: @sgroves I wouldn't subscribe to that. Sometimes you just want to use fancy words on purpose, e.g. to ironically make trivial things sound more sophisticated.

Comment: Quidquid Latine dictum sit, altum videtur :-)

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ferroequinology) labels the base noun '(humorous, nonstandard)' and only adds the agent noun as a derived form.

Comment: @ian_itor. The fact that OP is not willing to go with "a train themed room" is a pointer in that direction.

Comment: Maybe just ___ferroequine___ without the last -log(o)- part which seems to indicate a theory or wisdom (logos) of these iron horses. The word is Latin, but the logos part is Greek. If we swap the words (horse iron) and pass to Greek, there is [Hipposideros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipposideros). However, that is a genus of bat and not railroad-related.

Answer (score 12):

Train. Rail. Railway. I want a train-themed room. I want a rail-themed room. I want a railway-themed room.

Comment: Hello, Debra. While these may be the best options available, two have been offered already, one with the reference desired in an ELU 'answer'.

Comment: - What is related to trains? - Trains!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Have those answers been deleted? The only options suggested in answers visible at the time I'm writing this, are "locomotive" (wrong because it's more specific than "train"), "ferroequinologist" (ludicrously obscure), "gricer" (British-only and not widely understood even there). The words DebraH has suggested have been mentioned in comments to the question but that is not where answers should be posted. There is absolutely nothing wrong with writing an answer that mentions things only seen so far in comments.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Please don't confuse comments with answers. There is nothing wrong with turning someone's comment into a proper answer. However, DebraH: good answers on ELU have some explanation as to *why* they're right. Links to examples of usage in real life (as per Josh's comment on railroad) help make a better answer, as do other examples (as per David Richerby's answer talking about a "football book").

Comment: @AndyT I try very hard to stop the (what I consider totally) inappropriate answers 'You can use an [attributive] noun here' (covered ad nauseum already) /  'train[-]themed' etc (given by OP themself) / 'railroad-/railway-themed' (is this really at the level a site aimed at linguists requires?) / gricer / 'You might try ferroequinological' . As another contributor, Reg Dwight, has stated, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer.'  Josh chose to do this, then was undermined.

Comment: @David Richerby This cuts across Reg Dwight's opinion (mine also) of how ELU should operate.  Note that OP asks for a synonym for 'nautical' not 'shipping'; use of 'railroad[-]' etc is not an incorrect answer but is surely more ELL-relevant. "Is there a single word that might mean something similar to "of or relating to train operators, trains, or railroads"? ANS railroad-

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you feel the question is too basic and should be migrated to ELL then flag it and propose that. Otherwise, as far as I'm aware, the only appropriate answers are the basic ones. Are you saying that the question should only be answered in comments because the only answers are basic? That's not how Stack Exchange works. Answers should be posted as answers, not comments.

Comment: I have no problem with the question other than the fact that it opens the floodgates to simplistic and weird suggestions. I'd like to see 'Is there a single word that means "of or relating to train operators, trains, or railroads"? I do not mean attributive usages (such as railway-themed) or weird, non-standard terms.'

Comment: For the sake of personal experience as person who goes trainspotting and went to train-themed conventions is the US since childhood with my father and his friend.  This and @DavidRicherby answer are the most accurate and natural sounding to a US-based railfan.  I cannot recall anyone using an overarching word to describe all-thing-trains other than train or railroad.  (occasionally railway).

Comment: @RomaH "Railway" would be the UK version: the word "railroad" is almost nonexistent here. (Whereas "railway" is at least sometimes used in the US: e.g., three of the Class 1 railroads are BNSF Railway, Kansas City Southern Railway and Norfolk Southern Railway.)

Comment: "The trainful adjective" is a solved problem.  Which sounds right?  National Locomotive Museum.  National Train Museum.  National Rail Museum. National Railway Museum. National Railroad Museum.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not aware of any direct equivalent of "nautical" for railways. However, in the context of "A _____-themed room", there is nothing wrong with using a noun. "A train/railway/railroad-themed room" is the natural way of expressing the concept you're looking for. In general, when you need an adjective, a noun will do just fine: there's nothing wrong with talking about, say, "a football book" and the same goes for train/railway/railroad.

Answer (score 6):

In the UK at least, a person who is fascinated by railways is called a [*Gricer*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+gricer).  So you could ask for a gricer room.

However, the word isn't particularly common elsewhere, so you may not be understood.

Comment: The word "Gricer" isn't common or understood by everyone in the UK either. I've *never* heard of it. (Early 30s, lived all my life in the South East).

Comment: Yup. Normally refer to them as anoraks :-)

Comment: @AndyT It's an older term, probably quite common in the 1950s. But, linked definition notwithstanding, I think it refers specifically to a trainspotter rather than a general railway enthusiast.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: In my experience you would annoy a gricer if you called them a trainspotter.  People who identify themselves as gricers look down on trainspotters as mere anoraks.

Comment: This is about as appropriate as 'boataholic' as a synonym for 'nautical'.

Comment: I'm a Brit in his mid-40s.  I was very keen on railways as a child, my dad was very keen on railways, I currently takes his railway-mad son to them on regular occasions, I've lived in various places from Lancashire, Yorkshire, across the Midlands and down to the South East, and I'm fascinated by the English language and interesting words.  And I've never heard this word in my life.  Your chances of being understood start at zero and go down.  How can it be worse than zero?  Because "gricer" is most likely to be misheard as "greaser", which relates to bikers.

Comment: Never heard this term, and with only 20K Google hits neither has 99.9% of the English-speaking world. Also @Graham, worse than that still, 'greaser' can be an ethnic slur (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=GREASER&page=2)

Answer (score 4):

In USA, I've heard railroadiana <[web reference](http://www.railroadiana.org/shows/pgShows.php)>
"For many collectors [of railroad related stuff], going to railroadiana shows is one of the most enjoyable aspects of the hobby."

I want this room to be my railroadiana room.

Comment: Never heard that coinage either, but 435K Google hits for *'railroadiana'*

Answer (score 2):

Word meaning "of or relating to train operators, trains, or railroads"

In the UK or the US:

> 3. (**Railways**) the entire equipment, rolling stock, buildings, property, and system of tracks used in such a transport system –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/railway), *railway*

In the US:

> 2. A system of **railroad** track, together with the land, stations, rolling stock, and other related property under one management. –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/railroad), *railroad*

I want a [railroad/railway] themed room.

Answer (score 0):

Nautical is an adjective derived from the Greek word for boat. So the problem is there is no Greek word for train to draw from. locomotive, as a Latin-derived term, makes some sense here. The effort at ferroequinos above is similarly motivated, modern English loves to use Greek or Latin to make adjectives.

So I think you may need to make up a new word to capture the whole complex. Is there a king or God or inventor whose name could be turned into an adjective, someone people would naturally associate with trains? I order to make a new word stick it has to make some natural sense to people.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.